# Load child app controller using $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to understand the concept of "routeProvider". I am trying to load a childapp controller from the parent app. So in the above specified case the html gets rendered but not the expression value in the child App. Moreover I could see that the child controller is never invoked. The alert in the child controller is never prompted.

Following is the link to the code
http://tinyurl.com/h8yup5n

Comment: What's your exact problem? The Plunker works fine for me.

Comment: Hi Hinn,  if you click on the "Create Order" link now in the plunker, the message variable is not resolved. It comes up as {{ message }}, and there is an error ofcourse in the console (Updated the url few mins ago, can you take a look again please)

Comment: ok, writing an answer

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to include the second app in both your html and as a angular dependency.

Add

`<script src="create.js"></script>`

into index.html.

Modify the first line of `app.js` to look like this:

`var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', ['createApp']);`

Comment: Thanks for quick help. But another quick question, when I add controller to the sampleApp, none of the links work? Why is it so? I added the controller under the app definition as <div class="container" ng-controller="sampleController">

Comment: If you don't have a sampleController defined in JS, Angular will derp out. Accept answer if this worked, aswell, please :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I am not able to upvote the answer because of the insufficient reputation. Just started today.

Comment: You can accept. It's the tickmark below the vote arrows.See http://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png